# Excel apply a formula until the end of a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is my situation.

I am going to make a formula which will return me a Boolean value according to a value in other column. For example, IF
A1 = 0, B1 = FALSE
A2 = 1, B2 = FALSE

Here is the problem, I want this formula can apply when new data is being input. I solve it by pull the formula until B9999, but I don't like this. I want it B(?) will automatically find the value when A(?) is being input.

Thanks for your attention, please help me.

Comment: is this being written as a macro? or is it just an excel formula written straight into the cell?

Comment: If A1 is 0 then B1 is false; if A2 is 1 then B2 is false. If they are all going to be false then just put false all the way down column B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following formula in B1:

> =IF(A1="","",IF(**YOUR FORMULA HERE**,TRUE,FALSE))

This way as long as A1 is blank, B1 will also remain blank. If A1 has a value, then your formula will be calculated.

You can then pull the formula to the whole column.

Comment: 9999 rows might be enough. While it seems like a lot, it is less than ¹⁄₁₀₀ of a full column's 1,048,576 rows. Remember that the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) will extend down to the last cell used and extends across for the total number of columns used.